# Linking a string in Word VSTO addin Word.interop 2

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

In the code I am searching string and putting link beneath that string. But the problem is, that it is working only for the first word in the paragraph. How can I do foreach statement rightly?

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

private Word.Range FindAndReplace(Word.Range rngToSearch, object findText, object replaceWithText)
        {
            bool found = false;
            //options
            object matchCase = false;
            object matchWholeWord = true;
            object matchWildCards = true;
            object matchSoundsLike = false;
            object matchAllWordForms = false;
            object forward = true;
            object format = false;
            object matchKashida = false;                     
            object matchDiacritics = false;
            object matchAlefHamza = false;
            object matchControl = false;
            object read_only = false;
            object visible = true;
            object replace = false;
            object wrap = 1;

            //execute find and replace
            found = rngToSearch.Find.Execute(ref findText, ref matchCase, ref matchWholeWord,
                ref matchWildCards, ref matchSoundsLike, ref matchAllWordForms, ref forward, ref wrap, ref format, ref replaceWithText, ref replace,
                ref matchKashida, ref matchDiacritics, ref matchAlefHamza, ref matchControl);
          if (!found)
          {
            rngToSearch = null;
          }

          return rngToSearch;
        }

        private void Button3_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {
            Word.Document doc = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument;
            Word.Range rng = doc.Content;
            string searchTerm = @"<[0-9]-[0-9]{1;}-[0-9]{1;}/[0-9]{1;}>";
            string hyperlink = "";  //put your hyperlink stuff here

            foreach (Word.Paragraph paragraph in doc.Paragraphs)
            {
                Word.Range rngFound = FindAndReplace(rng, searchTerm, ""); //searching and wrapping.

                if (rngFound != null)
                {
                Word.Hyperlink hp = (Word.Hyperlink)
                    rngFound.Hyperlinks.Add(rngFound, hyperlink + rngFound.Text);
                }
            }
 }
```

1 )I have tired: `foreach (Word.Range docRange in doc.Words) {Word.Range rngFound = FindAndReplace(docRange, searchTerm, "")` It takes words one by one. And it is wery slow.
2) Also tried to use the Selection:

```
private Word.Selection FindAndReplace(Word.Selection rngToSearch, object findText, object replaceWithText)
        {
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
foreach (Word.Paragraph paragraph in doc.Paragraphs)
            {
                Word.Selection rngFound = FindAndReplace(app.Selection, searchTerm, ""); //searching and wrapping. 

               rngFound.Range.Hyperlinks.Add(rngFound.Range, hyperlink + rngFound.Text);
```

But now it does one word with one click. And in the end I solved it with that method. Look at my last comment.

3) I also tried:

```
foreach (Word.Paragraph paragraph in doc.Paragraphs)
                {
                    Word.Range rngFound = FindAndReplace(paragraph.Range, searchTerm, ""); //searching and wrapping.

                    if (rngFound != null)
                    {
                    Word.Hyperlink hp = (Word.Hyperlink)
                        rngFound.Hyperlinks.Add(rngFound, hyperlink + rngFound.Text);
                    }
```

And it does the work with the first words in paragraphs.

What I need to do to run it in all of my document Range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks. At the end I have>

```
Word.Selection FindAndReplace(Word.Selection rngToSearch, object findText, object replaceWithText) //funcija poiska 4erez range
        {
            bool found = false;
            //options
            object matchCase = false;
            object matchWholeWord = true;
            object matchWildCards = true;
            object matchSoundsLike = false;
            object matchAllWordForms = false;  
            object forward = true;
            object format = false;
            object matchKashida = false;
            object matchDiacritics = false;
            object matchAlefHamza = false;
            object matchControl = false;
            object read_only = false;
            object visible = true;
            object replace = false;
            object wrap = Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindStop;;

            //execute find and replace
            found = rngToSearch.Find.Execute(ref findText, ref matchCase, ref matchWholeWord,
                ref matchWildCards, ref matchSoundsLike, ref matchAllWordForms, ref forward, ref wrap, ref format, ref replaceWithText, ref replace,
                ref matchKashida, ref matchDiacritics, ref matchAlefHamza, ref matchControl);
            if (!found)
            {
                rngToSearch = null;
            }

            return rngToSearch;
        }

        private void Button3_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {
            int WordsCount = 0;

            int counter = 0;
            Word.Application app = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
            Word.Document doc = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument;
            Word.Range rng = doc.Content;
            string searchTerm = @"<[0-9]-[0-9]{1;}-[0-9]{1;}/[0-9]{1;}>";
            string hyperlink = "google.com";  //
            string s = rng.Text; // Pushing doc text to the string
            Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d*-\d*-\d*/\d*"); 
            WordsCount = regex.Matches(s).Count; // Using regex getting count of searchable words 





            while (WordsCount >= counter ) // knowing count of words we know how much iterations we need to do.  
                foreach (Word.Section paragraph in doc.Sections)
            {
                    Word.Selection rngFound = FindAndReplace(app.Selection, searchTerm, ""); //searching and wrapping.

                    if (rngFound != null)
                {

                        rngFound.Range.Hyperlinks.Add(rngFound.Range, hyperlink + rngFound.Text);

                }counter++; // counting iterations


                }
        }
```

And it is working. Thankyou Cindy for your good advice.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the code is returning "odd" results is the property setting for the `Find.Wrap` parameter. This was set to `1` which is the equivalent of the enum `wdFindcontinue`. This should *never* be used in code for Word's `Find` functionality as it causes the code to continue looping until what's being searched for is "found". If it can't be found, the code goes into an "infinite loop".

Usually, what's wanted is `0`, `wdFindStop` which means the search starts at the beginning of the specified search `Range` and continues to that range's end-point, then stops.

So change this line:

```
object wrap = 1;
```

to:

```
object wrap = Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindStop;  //or 0
```

I highly recommend using the full enum rather than the `int` equivalent unless there's an explicit reason to not do so. (Late-binding / PInvoke would be such a reason.) If nothing else, it makes the code much easier to read and understand, as this problem illustrates.

With that correction, the following test code works for me. I post this to show trouble-shooting using `System.Diagnotics.Debug.Print` helped me to track down the problem: I could compare each `paragraph` in the loop with what `rngFound.Text` was returning.

```
       Word.Document doc = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument;
        Word.Range rng = doc.Content;
        string searchTerm = @"<[0-9]-[0-9]{1;}-[0-9]{1;}/[0-9]{1;}>";
        string hyperlink = "";  //put your hyperlink stuff here

        foreach (Word.Paragraph paragraph in doc.Paragraphs)
        {
            rng = paragraph.Range;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(rng.Text);  
            Word.Range rngFound = FindAndReplace(rng, searchTerm, ""); //searching and wrapping.

            if (rngFound != null)
            {
            //Word.Hyperlink hp = (Word.Hyperlink)
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(rngFound.Text);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hey Cindy. I tried to change wrap on to your suggested statement. But the result is the same. If I have for example 2-16-9035/88, 2-16-8344/41, 5-17-43/12, 2-15-5027/137 in the document. The first 2-16-9035/88 will be wrapped and sikcle stops.

Comment: I currently can't do much, on a mobile device, but I did test quite thoroughly yesterday, using the sample given in the first question. Note that this only catches the first instance / paragraph, since that was the implied requirement, looping paragraphs. If you need something else you must be VERY SPECIFIC.